# How to remove an object from a std::vector

Tags: c++

So I have a vector of bullets that show up on the screen and I do not want these bullets to live forever. I want them to "die as soon as they go off screen or collide with an enemy. How can I make sure they are removed from the array and no longer take up memory.

code:

```
std::vector<Bullet> bulletArray;

for(int i=0; i<bulletArray.size(); i++)
{
    bulletArray[i].MoveBullet();
    bulletArray[i].Draw();
    if(bulletArray[i].PosY<0)
    {
        //Delete object forever 
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers which will work in this situation are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875103/how-to-erase-element-from-stdvector-by-index

Comment: bulletArray.erase(enemyArray.begin() + 1); This i have tried and i saw this post but i get this error : Error 2 error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'

Comment: You cannot erase an element of enemyArray from bulletArray.  You can only erase elements of bulletArray from bulletArray, because enemyArray is not bulletArray.  You can only use iterators from a particular vector to erase elements from that same vector, not any other vector.

Comment: @JonathanO In future please post purely C++-related questions like this on stackoverflow.com, _not_ here. Thanks.

Comment: @Arcane Engineer - This seems like a game development question to me. Maybe back off with the italics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. You can simply remove object i from the vector using `bulletArray.erase(bulletArray.begin() + i)` and then `i--` to process everything for the new bullet in i'th position. But this way vector will move all the object after the that specific bullet, meaning this kind of removal is O(bulletArray.size()).
2. But usually order of the bullets is not important, so you can simply put the last bullet  in the i'th cell, and only remove it's spot. This way it's much more faster since these operations are O(1). And it's implemented as `bulletArray[i] = bulletArray.back(); bulletArray.pop_back(); i--;`  again you need to decrement i by one to check this new object in this i'th position in the next loop.

Comment: In #2, you should use `swap` rather than a copy if bullets are moderately complex objects --- it is much faster if there is a string in it, for instance. Actually, it looks like a `vector` is the wrong data structure for this job.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni using swap will result in two copies, which is much more expensive to one copy! besides, using vector is not a bad idea in general, except std::vector is slow.

Comment: Good point. According to how `swap` and the copy constructor are implemented, either choice could be faster. We cannot say more without knowing what a `bullet` is. I think that this is the exact problem that is solved by the introduction of move constructors in C++11. If the OP is willing to use C++11 extensions, this looks like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I find that it's a good idea to add a flag (normally I call this "dead") to the objects.

Then you can do this (in pseudo-pythonic code):

```
// Processing
for obj in my_list:
  if obj has hit enemy:
    obj.dead = true
  if obj outside play area:
    obj.dead = true
// Rendering (at some different point)
for obj in my_list:
  render somehow
```

Then you can use the std::remove_if higher-order function (in algorithms) to remove the ones with the "dead" flag set. Remember to use std::erase to truncate the vector to the right point.

The main advantage of using this remove_if/erase is that it avoids problems when trying to remove elements while iterating the list.

Additionally, sometimes you may want to remove object X while processing object Y (in collision detection, such situations are normal) - we can do this easily without breaking any iterator objects.

(Note that iterator objects are normally only valid as long as no new elements are added or removed. Especially for std::vector)